# Found when user keep scrolling when is in the top, Android

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I want to know when the user keep scrolling (like when you want to update your timeline in Twitter?

Actually I just can use onScrollListener because I'm using [this](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) library that make listview capable to implements drag and drop of the listviews

What I want to do, is being capable to "minimize" this listview when the user make the "top to bottom" event, but its imposible to modify the OnTouchListener
What i am doing right now is the next one:

```
listOrders.getRecyclerView().addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState == recyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
               int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 56, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                int marginBottom = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layPra = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
                layPra.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                layPra.bottomMargin = marginBottom;
                frameOrders.setLayoutParams(layPra);
                listOrders.setScrollingEnabled(false);
                listOrders.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);

rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if (dy < 0) {
                    // Recycle view scrolling up...

                } else if (dy > 0) {
                    // Recycle view scrolling down...
                }
            }
        });
```